# Purpose of series resistors in this bipolar rectifier circuit?

Tags: power-supply, rectifier, bipolar

The following circuit uses two series resistors, one for each polarity of the supply. I understand function of smoothing caps and overvoltage zener diodes, but the resistors I do not. I would like to understand the function of these resistors and how to calculate what wattage these parts should be. Also, how critical is their resistance value?

[image: circuitimage]

Comment: Those aren't 'overvoltage zener diodes' - they're not there for protection. The series resistor + zener combination is acting as a crude [voltage regulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_diode#Voltage_regulator).

Answer (score 1):

It's a series resistor for the zener diode. One is needed to make the zenerdiode able to cut off the exessive voltage. The zenerdiode draws just that current which is needed (in addition to the load current) to drop the voltage to the zener voltage. This is the way how zenerdiodes are used as voltage regulators.

This principle is practical only for low power systems due the continuous dissipation in the zenerdiodes.

The wattage of the resistor: Let Ux = the maximun DC voltage in capacitors after the rectifier, for example 20V. It's about 1.4 x the output voltage of the transformer.

Calculate the voltage drop in the series resistor: Ux - Uout. If Ux = 20V then the drop is 8V. *NOTE the zenerdiode draws all the current that's needed for 8V drop in addition to the load current. The resistance is detemined in accordance with that.*

The dissipation in the resistor = (Ux - Uout)^2/R = (8V)^2/270Ohm = 0.24W

Theoretically 0.25W resistor is ok, but in practice it easily gets hot due poor cooling. Take at least 0.5W, if Ux=20V happens to be your case.

Answer (score 1):

Voltage regulation, and to a lesser extent filtering.

The resistors and the zener diodes together form a simple linear regulator.  The zeners set the output voltage, and the resistors set the current which flows through them.  If the resistors are too small, then the current through the zeners may be too big power is wasted heating them up.  If the resistors are too big, then they restrict the total current available. The current drawn by the load could reduce the current through the zeners to zero, then the voltage would begin to droop.

If you look at the zener datasheets, and start working out the performance of the regulator for different resistor values, you'll quickly see that this approach is only suitable for crude regulation and small currents.

The resistors will also form something of an RC filter with the caps, though that effect is not really separable from their task as part of a regulator.

Comment: This is a +/-12VDC circuit and those are 15V zeners. I thought the zeners were only to handle overvoltage conditions (anything above the nominal 12V). If I removed the zeners, but kept the caps and resistors, what voltage would my rails be?

Comment: Without the Zener diodes, the output voltage would depend on the voltage across the capacitors, and the voltage drop in the resistors due to the load current.

Comment: @disorder, are you sure?  There is part of the circuit we can't see, but there's a tiny hint in the lower-left corner "-35V".  If we assume that's relative to the junction of D2/D4 then there will be about 9.3 mA passing through the zeners at zero load.  That's about half the dissipation limit for the parts.  As the actual load increases, the current through the zeners will decrease (and the current through the resisters will remain constant).

Comment: That schematic is rather fuzzy.  If the diodes are really 1N963, they would be 12 volts.  There appears to be a "-35 volt" label on the bottom line, but I read the capacitors as rated for 25 volts - not good for a 35 volt supply.

Comment: @PeterBennett a pair of 25V caps in series would be suitable for a single-ended 35V supply.

Comment: @LawrenceNK1G: yes, but I'd assume that the -35 Volt is relative to the indicated ground.  We (well, I) always measure voltages relative to the indicated circuit "ground", not relative to some other random point in the circuit.

Comment: I agree that it is vague ... my best defense is "ground INSIDE the dashed box is not ground OUTSIDE the dashed box" :)

Answer (score 1):

The Zener diodes can only dissipate a certain amount of power. Also, their actual voltage drop varies from their rated voltage drop as the current through them varies.

The resistors are therefore to limit the current through the Zeners, attempting to keep the current to one that produces a tolerable voltage drop range and that doesn't dissipate excessive power in the Zeners. And in the resistors, for that matter.

This kind of regulator, a shunt regulator, is one of the least efficient. The load current causes a drop in the resistors and the Zeners are conducting more current to clamp the voltage. If the load current drops, the Zeners must conduct more current to counterbalance it.

It's an OK circuit if you can afford the wasted power through inefficiency or have a very small load. Otherwise a series regulator, linear or switching, is more efficient, though each comes with its own pros and cons.